# Get Max value of a DATE and an ID in order to filter results

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to get the latest "date" so the max value of "date" and from the same table I want the max value of "stand" also from the same ID.

I have tons of dates, stands for one ID but i only want to extract the latest.

im trying to save it into a function i dont know yet if thats the best idea. The rest of my query It's made of inner joins.
Datum is of type date.
stand is decimal(18,6)

```
DECLARE @MAXDATE DATE
DECLARE @MAXSTAND decimal(18,6)

SELECT @MAXDATE = MAX(Datum) FROM [dbo].[1] WHERE ID = ID
SELECT @MAXSTAND = Stand FROM [dbo].[2]WHERE ID = ID
```

Result I get:  @MAXDATE: 2106-10-13
Result I get: @MAXSTAND: 0.000000

Result I want: @MAXDATE: 2018-01-16
result I want: @MAXSTAND: 1098.000000

Comment: I don't understand the 2 lines : "Result from select @MAXDATE: 2106-10-13 Result from select MAXSTAND: 0.000000" and the other one

Comment: from @MAXDATE its of type DATE somehow i get "2106-10-13" as result yet i have nowhere in my database "2106-10-13", maybe its a format thing.

Comment: As from @MAXSTAND: "0.000000" I get all values as 0.

Comment: So it's result **you get** and result **you want**

Comment: Please read the first two paragraphs of the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question with proper sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server 2012 or higher, you can use the [`first_value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function:

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(Stand) OVER(ORDER BY Datum DESC)
FROM TableName
WHERE Id = @Id
```

This will return the value of `Stand` where the `Datum` column has the latest value for the specific `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

With the data provided, I don't think you need to do something else :

```
SELECT MAX(Datum), MAX(Stand)
FROM TableName
WHERE ID = @MyId
```

edit : You want it by ID, you can do this :

```
SELECT MAX(Datum), MAX(Stand), ID
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: the result i get: "2106-10-13" "140354231.000000"  looks like somewhere i have to format date i think and i also get one date and one. Is it possible to get from every ID It's highest date and value corresponing to that ID. I have mutiple ID's with many dates and stand

Comment: Please edit your question with the schema, we don't know the datatype here.

Comment: I have edited my question, is it possible to get from every ID It's highest "datum" and "stand" corresponing to that ID. I have mutiple ID's with many "Datum" and "stand"